# Getting HTTP 404 in Apache Solr after changing ports

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, solr, http-status-code-404

I installed Apache Tomcat with Solr on Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu instance) and set the server.xml to listen on port 80. It worked out until I decided to stop the Tomcat instance and change the port to 8080 (switching ports to prevent public access during development) and I am getting the following HTTP 404 error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at www.xxxxxxxxxx.com Port 8080
```

When I edit the server.xml config from 8080 back to 80 (my original setup port), it worked and gave me the Solr and Tomcat pages without problems.

From the above errors, it seems that Apache Tomcat is obviously responding to port 8080 but refuses to handle the requests on port 8080.

What should I do to solve the above problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you give suggests that this is not a tomcat error message. Stop tomcat and try to access port 8080 - if you still get the same error message, you have another server running on this port and your problem is that tomcat cannot bind to this port. Whatever you have running there obviously doesn't know about SOLR, thus the 404 message.